# Submitting form reloads the page using turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using turbolinks in rails and whenever I submit the form it reloads the page and gets submitted.

How can I stop reloading the page and also submitting the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a remote form with `data-remote="true"` attribute https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-with